# Open email attachment with my app

Tags: android, attachment, intentfilter

I would like to open email attachments with my app. I added that to my manifest file:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*.pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but when I click the attachment to open it from the email app I got permission denial error while starting intent.
I tried also add to the manifest that:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.email.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER"/>
```

but it didn't help either.
I tested on the android 2.3.3 and 4.1.2.
Is there something I forgot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was my error. I didn't notice, but I had in the manifest file exported set to false.